# Argument passing in c# does not work as should ? Inside function used reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, arguments

I am passing one parameter/object to the function "RefValTest(object oIn)" by the value but after function call is over object passed by the value is changed, that shoud not happened, right ?

```
    class MilanTest
    { 
        public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    class PR
    {

      public static object RefValTest(object oIn)
      { 

        PropertyInfo tProperty = oIn.GetType().GetProperty("SomeValue");
        tProperty.SetValue(oIn, 5, null);

        return null;
       }

     }
```

somewhere in the main:

```
        MilanTest x = new MilanTest ();
        //here is by compiler default x.Somevalue == 0

        PR.RefValTest(x);
        //here is by compiler default x.Somevalue == 5
```

How it is possible that after call of "PR.RefValTest(x)" value of object x.SomeValue is changed ?

Br,
Milan.

Comment: The object passed by value is not changed, only one of its property is changed.

Comment: @tafa: The *object* isn't passed by value; a *reference* is passed by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're confusing what you're passing, and passing an object "by value" never quite works.

When you pass a reference type (anything derived from `System.Object`), what you're passing is a reference *to* that object - not the object itself.  Essentially you're passing the memory address that the object's data is stored at.  Whether you pass this by reference or by value, what happens inside the method is that the address is followed *to your original object*.  Whether you pass a "pointer to the address" or "a copy of the address", the address itself doesn't change.

So, regardless of how you pass that type, you're going to find that the original object is what you're modifying.  Your alternative, if you really need this functionality, is to create a clone of the object and pass in the clone instead (or make your method create the clone itself).  That way the clone is modified instead of your original object.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thorsten, Jon,

you all answerd my question but Dan Puzey explained it in more details! Thanks to all !

Comment: @Milan: I let the linked article give more detail in this case - I've spent *far* too long writing about this over the years ;) (I'm in no way suggesting that you change the accepted answer, but please read over that article if you have any lingering doubts.)

Answer (score 2):

Very simply: what's being passed into the method is a *reference* to the object. You're then changing the data within that object. So when you look at the object again afterwards, you can see the change.

You don't need to use reflection to see this working - here's a simpler version of your code:

```
class MilanTest
{ 
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void RefValTest(MilanTest x)
    { 
        x.SomeValue = 5;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MilanTest t = new MilanTest();
        RefValTest(t);
        Console.WriteLine(t.SomeValue); // Prints 5
    }
}
```

See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: Additionally, when passing the parameter as "ref object oIn", you'd also be able to change the reference itself. That means "oIn = someOtherObject" would (in your sample) make "x" another object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the reference `oIn` but you can change its properties.

So inside your method, if you say

```
oIn = "SomeString";
```

on the outside you wouldn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. This **should** happen, whether you set the value directly or take the detour over reflection. This is what pass-by-reference means: you are interacting with the same object instance, not a copy.

Comment: Except that this *isn't* pass-by-reference, it's pass reference by value.

Comment: You may call it a "nitpick", but it's a source of significant confusion, particularly as C# *does* have proper pass-by-reference semantics with `ref`.

Comment: @Jon: I don't disagree. In the present case, though, the confusion seemed to me to be on a more fundamental level.